# What are the odds that 2 players heads-up in poker will both not make a pair or better by the river, assuming they only check?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, poker

Here is my current thinking, please let me know if it is correct. The result doesn't seem intuitive and I feel like I'm missing something, hence I am reaching out here.

52 - 4 = 48 cards remaining.
(4-1) * 4 = 12 "outs" for at least a pair
1 - (36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32) / (48 * 47 * 46 * 45 * 44) = 0.7798 that at least 1 out is drawn on board, since it is equal to 1 minus the probability that none of the outs are drawn (I don't the "1 -" but it felt natural). The chance of straights and flushes are much lower than pairing but would only add to 0.7798. So the answer to the title is at most 0.2201.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hello. There are lots and lots of different variants of poker, so it might help if you explicitly specify the rules of your variant in simple terms: how many cards are in the river, and how many cards are in each player's hands?

Comment: @Stef: I imagine it's Texas Hold'em: two cards in each hand (implied by the OP's analysis) and five cards on the board. (The board is dealt three cards first, then the fourth and fifth card individually, but that doesn't matter for this problem.) OP, you might want to edit this clarification into your question if I'm right, or else correct my misconception if I'm wrong.

Comment: OP: I would divide this into cases: (a) deuce-trey vs four-five, (b) deuce-trey vs deuce-four, (c) deuce-trey vs deuce-trey. Find out the probabilities of each case, and the conditional probability of avoiding a pairing for each case.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought the probability,  for two players with two hole cards each and five community cards, of neither player having even a pair (not counting straights or flushes) was

$$\left(\frac{52}{52}\times \frac{48}{51}\times \frac{44}{50}\times \frac{40}{49} \times \frac{36}{48}\right)\times\left( \frac{32}{47}\times \frac{28}{46}\right) \times \left(\frac{6}{45}\times\frac{27}{44}+\frac{24}{45}\times\frac{26}{44}\right) \\ \,\\ \approx 0.0834$$

based on the community cards being all different values, the first hand also being different values, and the second hand's first card either matching one of the first hand's values or not but still not matching any of the community cards' values.